# Backend error, when loading gzip csv

Tags: google-bigquery

I got the "backend error. Job aborted" , job ID below.
I know this question was asked, but I still need some help to try & resolve this.
what happen if this happen in production,we want to have a 5min periodic loads? 
thanks in advance

Errors:
Backend error. Job aborted.
Job ID: job_744a2b54b1a343e1974acdae889a7e5c
Start Time: 4:32pm, 30 Aug 2012
End Time: 5:02pm, 30 Aug 2012
Destination Table: XXXXXXXXXX
Source URI: gs://XXXXX/XXXXXX.csv.Z
Delimiter: ,
Max Bad Records: 99999999

Answer (score 0):

This job hit an internal error. Since you ran this job, BigQuery has been updated to a new version, and a number of internal errors have been fixed. Can you retry your job?